# C# and Database With Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2013, desktop-application

How to establish DB connection in VS 2013? I am making an inventory System. I have done it 3-4 Times. but I'm using VS 2013 for the first Time. Please tell me how can i Create DB and use it. Just a Beginner.

Comment: I'm using VS2013. There is no localDB .. How i can create database and use it?<p>I'm trying to make an inventory system.. I have done it 4 times using VS 2005 and VS 2008.. I'm back here after a very long time. I saw some MSDN tutorials.. But all those were about Dragging From DataSource to Windows Form.. 
Can you guys help me by telling me How to establish a DB Connection. ? </p>
Just a Beginner... Thnx :)

Comment: you want to use VS as the IDE for your database design, or connect to your database using c#?

Comment: What did you use previously?

Comment: Also, if you have more information to add, edit your own question and add it in there, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2013, go to the menu "View > Server explorer". dock panel will appear to left or right of IDE. You can see the list "Data Connection" right click on that to create new sql database. If you want to access the existing database go through Add Connection.